# Simulation not happening in a particle system with sphere with hair particles

Tags: particles, hair

I created a sphere and applied hair particles (Pink Color) on it and activated the simulation. But when I used this "hair sphere" as an object in a particle system, the simulations are not happening in all the particles. Its only happening to the first particle. Any solutions?

Screenshot
[image]

Blend File
[image]

Comment: provide blend file

Comment: I guess you should use the Particle Instance modifier on the sphere instead of using it as the instance object in another particle system.

Comment: @Chris Added the blend file

Comment: @3DBear Thanks for the suggestion. I will try that

Comment: you cannot use another particle system as instance of a particle system

Comment: @ChrisAny other method to suggest? Thank You